# how to write excel files on r studio?

Tags: r, excel

```
Loading required package: rJava
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘rJava’:
 .onLoad failed in loadNamespace() for 'rJava', details:
  call: dirname(this$RuntimeLib)
  error: a character vector argument expected
Error: package ‘rJava’ could not be loaded
```

Comment: You've posted an error message and not the code that caused it. What did you type? Be as complete as possible.

Comment: You are obviously using a package that needs *another* package, `rJava`. Install `rJava`.

Answer (score 0):

Normally with:

```
write.csv(YOUR_VARIABLE, file = "NAME_OF_YOUR_FILE.csv")
```

I need to see your code to make yure what's the error. But if I understand good, you cannot access the `rJava` package. Did you add the `Rtools` to the `Path` system enviroment variable?

Answer (score 0):

Use openxlsx.

df is a dataframe:

```
write.xlsx(df, file = "mydataframe.xlsx")
```